# In echarts，How to make the two x axes fixedly displayed on the left and right sides of a line

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to do like this(https://echarts.baidu.com/ecg-storage/img/x95J-28WIB.png?v=1556263163940) ,

At first I want to implement this on a single x-axis,But when the amount of data on both sides is inconsistent,I get this(https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=x95J-28WIB&v=3)

So I want to show them by separating the two x-axes;how should I do?(echart v4);thx!